# A free online room with long/no time controls

Tags: texas-hold-em, online, mtt, sit-and-go

Me and my friends want to play some Sit-n-goes or tournaments with play money (not real money). We want to create private rooms, without people from the outside. The best option would bee MTTs with rebuys.

We played on the “World poker Club” website. But the time controls are too fast, it is almost not enjoyable for a simple friends round. We want the time to be adjuatable or at least long or even play without time controls.

Are there some stable sites/apps that match the criteria?

Comment: What am I doing wrong? When I enter pokernow.club I get a message that this site cannot be reached.
Thanks!

Comment: @bob that could have many reasons. I suggest you open a new question here on the Forum. This question is already answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, pokernow.club is a great site that lets you customize the game, including the time limit to make a decision. you and your friend can all play from a browser.

Comment: indeed a good place.